How to Set Mobs to Spawn at Certain Time Bedrock
I'm making a very specific "Element Mob" video, where there are extra hyped-up mobs that do a lot of damage, not giving me enough time to explain the mod and read the "instructions". Is there a way to make sure I don't get killed before I do my "preliminary work"? (no, it's not a skill issue)

Start your game on Peaceful
Start your game on the peaceful difficulty, where no Mobs spawn, then as soon as you are ready change it to another difficulty, so the mobs can start spawning. This can be done in the settings or with the difficulty command.
